# Why eth_getLogs returns empty result for Ethereum account address?

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, events, addresses, logs

I'm developing an Ethereum platform and need to fetch the events log of a desired address. I found a code like this:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"topics":["0x000000000000000000000000a94f5374fce5edbc8e2a8697c15331677e6ebf0b"]}],"id":74}'
```

but when I replace my own address in this code, I receive an empty result as below:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[]}
```

May you tell me what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

An ethereum log entry contains a list of *topics*. This list contains the contract address, event's signature and *indexed* parameters.

If you want to filter events with your address then it has to be included in an event as an indexed parameter.

For example standard ERC-20 tokens have the event `event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)`, and you can filter by sender and recipient address.

If your address wasn't included as an indexed parameter getLogs will return an empty list.

Comment: Ismael, I have not any problem with ERC-20 tokens logs, the issue I have face with is logs of ETH itself.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Since ether transfers do not generate any events you cannot use getLogs to retrieve them. I answered similar question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84275.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try using the following format for the request, just replace ADDRESS with the address that you want, TOPIC with the topics signatures that you want and the ENDPOINT with the HTTP endpoint of your node :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"method": "eth_getLogs","params":[ {"address": "ADDRESS","topics":["TOPIC"]}], "id":1,"jsonrpc": "2.0"}' ENDPOINT
```

'