# eth_getLogs was only return erc20 tokens

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, addresses, cpp-ethereum, logs

i have used below command to get every logs on the special blocks but its only return erc20 token logs and ethereum transactions was not listed.

my geth command:

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"fromBlock": "0x9C98BE", "toBlock": "0x9C98BE"}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:25545
```

my command just return ***147*** transactions:

https://pastebin.com/ybYz1k4q

etherscan was return ***170*** transactions:

https://etherscan.io/txs?block=10262718

Anyone can explain where is the etherum transactions (Not ERC20 Transactions) on eth_getLogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `eth_getLogs` returns transactions that generated a log entry. Ether transfers between regular accounts do not generate a log so they will not be included.

Comment: thank you and how to get the list of transactions between regular accounts?

Comment: @farhadjafari I don't know an api call that will return that list. An option is iterating all blocks in the range an examining each transaction for transfers.